# Having Text Box accept Numbers Backspace and a Decimal place

Tags: vb.net

I need to make the text box only accept Numbers Decimals and the Backspace. This is what I have so far and it works great for numbers and backspace but I have no idea what to do for periods. So any help would be great.

```
    Private Sub txtlength_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtlength.KeyPress
    If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Comparing `e.KeyChar` to `"."` doesn't do what you need?

Comment: you should also handle Delete

Comment: I cannot figure how to Compare e.KeyChar to "." or at least make it work in this code and to @Plutonix ControlChars.Back Handles backspace

Answer (score 1):

```
e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Back Or e.KeyChar = ".")
```